# Android Flip ImageView and Change Image

Tags: android

I have an Image View in my activity, When i click on Image View this Image view has to flip and change to other image, How to do this.?

Comment: Post the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

[Refer to this link.](https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip) It is a github library.Where, in adapter you change your images after completing of flip.This library gives you similar flip as in Flipboard application.